# Laravel - cache partial view during a foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-blade

How can I cache a blade file?

Sample code:

```
@foreach ($files as $file)
   @include('partials.file')
@endforeach
```

If there are 100 files, then the blade will load 100 times. Is there a way to cache it or something? If there are queries in the partial blade file, it may take a long time.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you dont need to worry about caching the blade templates, laravel compiles the blade templates into raw php and creates a cached version for it but these things are internal and worrying about it its pointless.

you can of course find many ways such us building `View()->render()` string and just output its into a view take a look at the following question

[Elegant way to run nested loops in views (Laravel)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures)

Answer (score 0):

The Blade compiler caches a single instance of each view. So if you are using a Blade template then you're only "including" the view once.

It's true that using the PHP compiler will result in one include per @include. However, it really is unlikely that this will cause a significant performance hit. If you can provide any references to the contrary that would be good.

Ultimately, if you are really concerned about including a file in a template, place the loop content inline and remove the abstraction. That way, your loop has zero includes and your problem is solved.